# How to find out which package a command belongs to

Tags: package, functions

I have found a command `M-x project-find-regexp`, how can I find out from where it comes from, ELPA/Melpa package or part of GNU/Emacs?

Comment: `describe-function` gives you a link to the corresponding file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`describe-function`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Name-Help.html) to get information about a function: `C-h f project-find-regexp RET` (or `F1 f project-find-regexp RET`). The first line is something like

```
project-find-regexp is a compiled Lisp function in `project.el'.
```

Click on the file name, or move the cursor to it and press RET. If you have the source code, this opens the file containing the function definition. Now press `C-h f` (`find-file`); this comes pre-filled with the path to the directory containing the file. Press `C-g` to cancel. (Alternative ways to find the directory include `M-x pwd RET`; this makes it harder to copy-paste from.)

From the directory path, you should be able to tell whether it's part of Emacs (e.g. under `/usr/share/emacs/VERSION/lisp` on a typical Linux system), a third-party file installed either through an OS-level package or manually (under a directory called `site-lisp`), or through Emacs's ELPA package mechanism (under `.emacs.d/elpa` in your home directory).

If you don't have the source code of the file that defines the function, you'll only get something like

```
project-find-regexp is an interactive compiled Lisp function.
```

In this case, you can run `M-: (find-function 'project-find-regexp)`. You'll get an error message with the location where Emacs expects to find the source file. Press `ESC ESC ESC` to dismiss the error message.